# How to update section in the Mongo collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, heroku, mongoose

This is my server code:

```
router.route('/addComment')
.post(function(req, res) {
  appRequest.update({"_id": req.body._id}, {$push:{comments:req.body.comments}}) // appRequest is my collection
});
```

Here is how I am defining my collection:

```
var locations = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    comments: [{
        identifier: String,
        text: String
    }]
});
```

I want to update the comments and append the user new comment to the comments array.

When I try to call the `/addComment` URL, I get the following in the logs (I am hosting it in Heroku):

> at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST
>   path="/addComment" host=discounts-oman.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=f77cc261-e58a-4eea-a7ad-f74af57972f4 fwd="94.185.30.228"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30010ms status=503 bytes=0
>   protocol=https

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get [H12 errors](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout) when the request times out. It times out because you are not sending any response back to the client. A response can, for example, be sent like this (if the rest of your code is correct):

```
router.route('/addComment').post(function (req, res) {
  appRequest.update(
    { _id: req.body._id },
    { $push: { comments: req.body.comments } },
    {},
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json(error);
      }

      return res.status(204).json();
    });
});
```

`res.json()` is for JSON response. You can use `res.send()` for generic responses.